# List throwing UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java

I have the sample code below:

```
String[] patternArray = {"1","2","3"};
List<String> patternCheck = Arrays.asList(patternArray);
patternCheck.add("4");
```

and the following exception was thrown

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
```

My question is why I am not able to add new string to my list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Arrays.asList(..)` return an unmodifiable collection. If you want to modify it, make a copy:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(..))
```

Alternatively, you can use [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
List<String> list = Lists.newArrayList("1", "2", "3");
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be parametrized (`ArrayList<String>`)?

Comment: since Java 7 - no, the type is inferred from the left-hand side

Answer (score 7):

Because `Arrays.asList(patternArray);` returns a **fixed-size list**, e.g. you cannot add more elements.

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.asList()` returns an unmodifiable, fixed-size list.

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.asList()` returns a fixed-size list. You can't add elements to it.